# Recommending websites that are gentle on introducing advanced math concepts?

Tags: book-recommendation

I don't have a math background, but I am an experienced programmer, and don't have problem in reading some introductory science books, and I would like to know more about some advanced math topics (well... At least to me it is), like tensors, differential geometry etc.

I have come across a math web site (www.mathsisfuncom) which I found to be sort of like what I was looking for (a topic-based organization of contents - so it is easier for me to find what I want, and newbie/kid-friendly at the same time), but the difficulty level is quite basic to me.

Are there any websites that can be re commended to me that can meet my needs?

Comment: There's always wikipedia...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extremely gentle introduction to algebraic geometry with pictures. http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/graph/algcurve.html

Comment: Thanks, it would be useful, but are there also some websites that include many different topics altogether?